# IIS7 URLRewrite on a PHP site

Tags: php, iis-7, rewrite

I have a PHP site running on IIS7 and I need to add some URL rewriting, but so far it seems to be ignoring my rule.  Here's the rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="VCard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="\?user=(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.otherserver.com/vcard.aspx?user={R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When using the UI to test my regex, it says that http://www.myserver.com/?user=123456 does match the rule, and that R:1 is "123456".  But when I try to access the actual url it doesn't appear to work.

The logging doesn't seem too helpful:

```
2010-10-26 14:22:07 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX GET / user=12345 80 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/8.0.552.11+Safari/534.10 200 0 0 187
```

As I mentioned above, the site itself is in PHP (which I'm less familiar with hosting on IIS).  Could that be preventing the rewriting module from running?  Am I missing a critical step somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url match is for just the URL before the querystring, like folder/vcard.aspx.

It's probably a condition for {QUERY_STRING} that you need instead.  Set .* for the url if you want to catch everything.  Just be careful you don't run into a loop for that query.

This may be helpful:
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/04/20/url-parts-available-to-url-rewrite-rules.aspx

It shouldn't matter that it's PHP.  The redirecting occurs before it processes PHP.